# Google Cloud Build Deploy Failing with BadStatusCodeError

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm deploying a new DotNet app to Google Cloud App Engine and it gets all the way through the build process but then it's failing on this version check for some mystery reason. Here's the error:

```
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
ERROR
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.
> 
}
}
"status": "INTERNAL"
"message": "Internal error encountered.",
"code": 500,
"error": {
BadStatusCodeError: HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-id>/services/api/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '500', 'content-length': '109', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Fri, 06 Dec 2019 02:53:27 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>
```

Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: Do you already have a version deployed to the "default" service? Change the service name to "default" and try again.

Comment: @JohnHanley I thought that might be the problem too so I deployed a default service earlier today (NodeJS which had no problems) but even after the deployment of the default it still errors out. Just as a test I deployed the application that's having the issue as default and it had the same error except the service name in the URL was "default". Maybe it's something weird with using the "runtime: custom" flag in app.yaml?

Comment: What happens if you change the service name for this deployment to default?

Comment: @JohnHanley funny I was just testing that as you wrote your comment. Same issue but the URL changes to match the service name of "default".

Comment: 1) Does this app work if you deploy manually. 2) Anything in Stackdriver?

Comment: @JohnHanley Nothing in stackdriver aside from the error I already posted. However, deploying manually didn't help either BUT it I noticed something while it was doing it. The build was using a Dockerfile that was a template that had the wrong entrypoint! Fixing the entrypoint and going through cloudbuild again worked. So the error from the cloudbuild process was totally misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this issue the problem may be that your Dockerfile is pointing to the wrong entry point. Correcting it solved the problem for me, hopefully it does for anyone else who finds themselves in front of this error.